# I dont get the Result i expected when i want to get my Telegram Chatbot id

Tags: http, telegram, telegram-bot

I Try to get my Chatbot id from my Telegram chatbot.

Normally you should write your API Key inside this URL

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<myapikey>/getUpdates
```

and i should receive something like this:

```
{
  "ok": true,
  "result": [
    {
      "update_id": 83xxxxx35,
      "message": {
        "message_id": 2643,
        "from": {...},
        "chat": {
          "id": 21xxxxx38,
          "first_name": "...",
          "last_name": "...",
          "username": "@username",
          "type": "private"
        },
        "date": 1703062972,
        "text": "/start"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

but when i try to get my id, i recieve this:

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "result": []
}
```

someone know what i did maybe wrong, or how i can fix this?

Greetings!

i tried using http instead of https, i also tried to use other links, aswell for different variations of my api key

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<myapikey>/getUpdates
```

Answer (score 0):

An empty result indicates that the Bot has no unprocessed messages.

You'll need to start a conversation with our new bot, send him a message, then the `result` array in the `getUpdates` call will contain that message.

---

> aswell for different variations of my api key

There are no *different variantions* of your api key, it's always in the format of:

```
https://api.telegram.org/bot<MY-TOKEN>/<METHOD>
```